# TailwindCSS dynamically change text color to contrast background

Tags: tailwind-css, sidebar

I have a semi-transparent sidebar with some background filters, on a mostly dark background

[image: semi-transparent sidebar]

When scrolling further down, the text gets on the white section and gets really hard to read

[image]

Is it possible to dynamically change the text color to be dark when the contrast between the text and anything under it is too low? If not through only Tailwind/normal CSS, then how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically adjust text color based on background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195738/dynamically-adjust-text-color-based-on-background-image)

Comment: It's not specifically just an image, there are other different-colored elements under the sidebar too, not a single image

Answer (score 2):

Its not a perfect fix, but I had a similar issue and I was able to use [Tailwind's blend modes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/mix-blend-mode):

```html
<div class="bg-gray-400 mix-blend-difference" />
```